# Display previous attendance figure

Tags: powerbi, dax, formula, powerbi-desktop

I have a table 'Date' with a column[Attendance] which has a mixture of values and zeros. I am looking for a code for Power BI that would display the previous attendance in a calculated column next to the attendance column so that I can use the information in a visual to show the difference of attendance between the 2 matchdays, unless there is a better way of doing this.

If site has zero in attendance then it was closed, if we could display a zero or "Site Closed" text.

| Date | Attendance | Last Games Attendance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06/01/24 | 0 | Site Closed |
| 07/01/24 | 52314 | Site Closed |
| 08/01/24 | 0 | Site Closed |
| 09/01/24 | 0 | Site Closed |
| 10/01/24 | 16895 | 52314 |
| 11/01/24 | 0 | Site Closed |
| 12/01/24 | 0 | Site Closed |
| 13/01/24 | 48536 | 16895 |
| 14/01/24 | 78236 | 48563 |
| 15/01/24 | 12247 | 78263 |
| 16/01/24 | 0 | Site Closed |
| 17/01/24 | 52314 | 12247 |

I am not sure where to start with this, I can get it to work on excel with a different set of data using an INDEX and MATCH formula but haven't got a high level of experience using Power BI.

I have tried the below, which just populates the row below

```
PreviousAttendance = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Date'[Attendance]),
    FILTER(
        'Date',
        'Date'[Date] = EARLIER('Date'[Date]) - 1
    )
)
```

When I remove the -1 it fills the correct row but just with the same figure that is in the attendance row not the previous attendance figure.

Result from Andrii's suggestion, just about there.

```
Date          Attendance             Last Games Attendance
06/01/24          0                  Site Closed
07/01/24      52314                  Site Closed
08/01/24          0                  Site Closed
09/01/24          0                  Site Closed
10/01/24      16895                  52314
11/01/24          0                  Site Closed
12/01/24          0                  Site Closed
13/01/24       48536                 16895 = Result from code 52314 
14/01/24       78236                 48563
15/01/24       12247                 78263 = Result from code 48563
16/01/24          0                  Site Closed
17/01/24       52314                 12247
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Last Game Attendance Number = 
VAR CurrentDate = 'Date'[Date]
VAR LastAttendanceDate = 
    MAXX(
        FILTER(
            'Date',
            'Date'[Date] < CurrentDate && 'Date'[Attendance] > 0
        ),
        'Date'[Date]
    )
RETURN
    IF(
        'Date'[Attendance] = 0,
        BLANK(),
        LOOKUPVALUE('Date'[Attendance], 'Date'[Date], LastAttendanceDate)
    )
```

after that you can create another column that would produce the label:

```
Last Games Attendance Label = 
IF('Date'[Last Game Attendance Number] = BLANK(), "Site Closed", FORMAT('Date'[Last Game Attendance Number], "0"))
```

Comment: Hi Andrii, It worked for the first game (10/01/24) (52314) but then the second game on the 13/01/24 was the same result as the first attendances (52314) instead of 16895. It them worked correctly again on the 14/01/24 (48563). It seems to work, then duplicate the , then work again.

Comment: Oops, sorry, that was my first unsuccessful attempt which produced the same result you got. Editing the answer with the hopefully working version ;)

Comment: No worries Andrii, Just about there.

Comment: Have you tried the updated version, Barry?

Comment: Hi Andrii, Yes apologies for not coming back to you, it works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
PreviousAttendance = 
VAR var1 = Dates[Date]
RETURN
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Dates[Attendance] ),
    FILTER ( Dates, Dates[Date] = var1 - 1 )
)
```

Comment: Hi Vilmar, Thanks for the suggestion. This drops the attendance for that day to the row below and not the previous attendance into the same row.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**