How to fill down on a measure in Power BI
I would like to auto fill down the column 'Last Games Attendance' which is a measure and to show like the table below, this is an extension of an already correctly answered question that was from last month which I have added below.
Original question for reference.
I have a table 'Date' with a column[Attendance] which has a mixture of values and zeros. I am looking for a code for Power BI that would display the previous attendance in a calculated column next to the attendance column so that I can use the information in a visual to show the difference of attendance between the 2 matchdays, unless there is a better way of doing this - Answered already in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/78064438/12089221
Last Game Attendance Number = 
VAR CurrentDate = 'Date'[Date]
VAR LastAttendanceDate = 
    MAXX(
        FILTER(
            'Date',
            'Date'[Date] < CurrentDate && 'Date'[Attendance] > 0
        ),
        'Date'[Date]
    )
RETURN
    IF(
        'Date'[Attendance] = 0,
        BLANK(),
        LOOKUPVALUE('Date'[Attendance], 'Date'[Date], LastAttendanceDate)
    )

New Query
If site has zero in attendance then it was closed, could it auto-fill down from the result of the above measure, I originally asked for it to show 'Site Closed' but this isn't helping on a new dashboard I am creating. The below was the code I had originally asked for to show 'Site Closed'
Last Games Attendance Label = 
IF('Date'[Last Game Attendance Number] = BLANK(), "Site Closed", FORMAT('Date'[Last Game Attendance Number], "0"))

The table below is how I would like it to look, where the code above would have populated the column 'Last Games Attendance' with 'Site Closed' if the attendance was zero.



Date
Attendance
Last Games Attendance




06/01/24
0
0


07/01/24
52314
0


08/01/24
0
52314


09/01/24
0
52314


10/01/24
16895
52314


11/01/24
0
16895


12/01/24
0
16895


13/01/24
48536
16895


14/01/24
78236
48563


15/01/24
12247
78263


16/01/24
0
78263


17/01/24
52314
12247




You need to add a calculated column and check if the LastAttendanceDate is blank. If it is, it means there was no previous game with attendees, so you return 0. Otherwise, the LOOKUPVALUE finds the attendance on the LastAttendanceDate :
Last Games Attendance = 
VAR CurrentDate = 'Date'[Date]
VAR LastAttendanceDate = MAXX(
    FILTER(
        'Date',
        'Date'[Date] < CurrentDate && 'Date'[Attendance] > 0
    ),
    'Date'[Date]
)
RETURN
IF(
    ISBLANK(LastAttendanceDate),
    0,
    LOOKUPVALUE('Date'[Attendance], 'Date'[Date], LastAttendanceDate)
)



Hi Amira, Thanks for your answer. It works in most parts but seems to fill up not down, it may be my formatting but how would I revers the way it fills, so basically in my column it shows on the 8th & 9th it is showing 16895 and on the 11th & 12th it is showing 48536.

If you share more data I can work on it. My answer is aligned on what you shared for 8th & 9th it should show 52314 like you mentioned

Hi Amira, I had another table that had a column that had the previous game attendance figure calculated there, so used that instead of 'Date'[Attendance]. Thanks for the reply and getting me 99% there, have a great day

Barry it is my pleasure to help :)
